# ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

При вводе любой команды через командную строку Windows возникает такая ошибка: ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away. Происходит реконнект и команда срабатывает нормально.

Comment: `Происходит реконнект и команда срабатывает нормально.` Уточните. Следует ли понимать, что после ввода команды и нажатия Enter (или ввода \g) сообщение об ошибке, реконнект и выполнение команды происходят без дополнительных Ваших действий?

Comment: да, все так, ввожу команду, жму Enter, сообщение об ошибке, реконнект и команда выполняется, использую OpenServer

Comment: Также уточните, `через командную строку Windows` - это на самом деле команда вводится в окне консольного клиента mysql.exe?

Comment: ну вход выполняется путем прописывания пути до mysql.exe, версия если что MySQL 5.5

Comment: `вход выполняется путем прописывания пути до mysql.exe` Совсем не понял, что имеется в виду... в любом случае, попробуйте посмотреть тут: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html , там много причин и соответственно мероприятий по преодолению.